# React native push notifications Enable/Disable

Tags: react-native, react-native-push-notification

Hi everyone I setup  `react-native-push-notification` in my app with theese packages

```
import PushNotification from 'react-native-push-notification';
 import PushNotificationIOS from '@react-native-community/push-notification-ios';

import firebase from '@react-native-firebase/app';
import '@react-native-firebase/messaging';
```

I cant send ,show and click notificaitons thats all okay.

I just want to disable to show notification when app in the Messages screen.

in screen

```
import PushNotification from 'react-native-push-notification';
import firebase from '@react-native-firebase/app';
import '@react-native-firebase/messaging';

  componentDidMount() {
     this._unsubscribe = this.props.navigation.addListener('focus', () => {     
      this.getMessageUsersList();
      //PushNotification.abandonPermissions()
      Orientation.lockToPortrait();
    });
    
    PushNotification.abandonPermissions()
```

function

```
 requestPermissions  () {
    firebase
      .messaging()
      .requestPermission()
      .then((status: FirebaseMessagingTypes.AuthorizationStatus) => {
        console.log('requestPermissions')
        if (status === 1) {
          console.log('Authorized');
        //  onMessage();
        } else {
          console.log('Not authorized');
        }
      })
      .catch((e) => console.log(e));
  };
```

unmount

```
  componentWillUnmount() {
 
    this.requestPermissions()
  }
```

It really disables notificatons but when I anvigate to antother screen , it still disabled so I can't show notification.

What should I change. Thank you